# Google's Street View API for Android doesn't show Photosphere points

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view, panoramas, photosphere

I have 2 Google Street View Projects.

One is using the Street View API for Web. 
The second is using the Street View API for Android.

When I display Parameters like Lat:-13.163300, Lng:-72.545601.

The web-application finds no 'real' Street View but a 360° photo (uploaded by a google user - I think it's called Photosphere). Wonderful! That's all I need

Sadly the Android App doesn't find anything to display!?!? Black Screen! (yes...other locations are working in the App ;) )

Any ideas why the Street View API for Web find Panorama Images and the API for Android doesn't?

I create my Street View for Android like this:

```
final LatLng markerPosition = new LatLng(-13.163300, -72.545601);

SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment = (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(
        new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(final StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
                mStreetViewPanorama = panorama;
                mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition(markerPosition, 1000); //--search in radius of 1000 meter
                mStreetViewPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(StreetViewActivity.this);
            }
});
```

Comment: Did you find something having same problem